# 2 similar looking Android UIs sharing the same Activity/Fragment?

Tags: java, android

I have 2 different "pages/ui" in my Android app, that both look quite similar, except a TextInput is missing in one of the views and the headers, dropdowns, etc are different. Here is what I mean:

[image]

So here I have the views. The first view and logic **already exist** and I have to create a new feature for the **second view** which is kind of similar but stems from a different path in the app, and the form is submitted to a different endpoint.

**My Question:**

My coworker suggested to just reuse the existing **FistViewActivity** and just hide the "secondlabel..." and "secondInput.." and use an enum to decide if the app is in the **first flow/path** or the **second flow/path** and then decide the submit endpoint based on that.

I am new to Android but I think this approach is not good compared to creating a new Activity **SecondViewActivity** for the second view. This is because combining both into FirstView makes it coupled and complex (using enum to depict flow, deciding which endpoint to submit, which fields to check before submitting etc).

Any thoughts? I could most certainly be wrong, but I prefer decoupling compared to "hiding" and using an enum to depict path.

Answer (score 0):

The first question that possibly needs to be asked is one of design: "Do we need 2 screens that are so similar in the first place?"

If you do, I think that for the most part, this is a good idea. I have an opinion of programming that is "if you're copying and pasting, you're doing something that could be abstracted"

What you could do is have an [abstract class](https://beginnersbook.com/2019/03/kotlin-abstract-class/) that defines most of the behaviour, and then your two implementing classes simply define the differentiating behaviour.

If you use [MVVM](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) or [MVP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93presenter) (I really recommend using one or the other) - you could do the same thing or have entirely different dependencies that model separate behaviour.

```
class SharedViewModel: ViewModel() {
    // Can share behaviour
}

class DistinctInstance {
    //Multiple instances
}

abstract class AbstractActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    protected val viewModel: SharedViewModel by lazy {
        SharedViewModel() //<-- only gets the SVM instance once, and only when accessed 
    }
    
    abstract val distinctInstance: DistinctInstance
    
    abstract fun someAbstractBehviour()
    
    protected open fun OverrideableBehaviour() {
        //You may need to do something different at some point
    }
    
    fun doesSomethingCommon() {
        // actual implmentation
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        someAbstractBehviour()
    }
}
```

I think the main area of concern is not creating the concept of "[BaseActivity](https://dev.to/antonholmberg/the-baseclass-anti-pattern-16il)" and ensuring that you don't have "[Lasagne code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code#:%7E:text=Lasagna%20code%20refers%20to%20code,changes%20in%20all%20other%20layers.)" - and keep [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles in mind.

Comment: Just an FYI: I do recommend not asking open-ended questions, because one answer is usually never enough. https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Normally on SO we don't go in to practice as that can be highly opinionated.